# Extend Account struct in anchor

Tags: anchor, anchor-accounts

Does Anchor support a way to extend/otherwise reduce duplication between Accounts for separate instructions? The way I'm writing instructions right now is by doing (obviously not all are `AccountInfo` in practice, just for demonstrative purposes):

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix1<'info> {
    pub acc1 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc2 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc3 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc4 : AccountInfo<'info>,
}

pub fn ix_1(ctx: Context<Ix1>) -> Result<()>{
    // Do stuff
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Ix2<'info> {
    pub acc1 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc2 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc3 : AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub acc5 : AccountInfo<'info>,
}

pub fn ix_2(ctx: Context<Ix2>) -> Result<()>{
    // Do more stuff
}
```

This is kind of annoying since for both instructions (and most of my other instructions too) `acc1, acc2,acc3` are the same yet I have to type this over and over again. This is especially tedious since in practice these have some extra constraints which means I'm duplicating ~50 LOC for each instruction. Is there a way I can make a basic template I extend or something else to avoid retyping these everytime?

Answer (score 1):

This feature will come in Anchor 0.30.0.
At the moment i don't know a way to improve this beside using native and use the account iterator or just passing in all the accounts in all instructions which is of course not optimal.

This could be the new feature maybe:
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/idl/programs/relations-derivation/src/lib.rs
Maybe you could try build it from source.

Comment: Aw man that sucks. Could you share a bit more details of how this will work in 0.30 / link the pr that adds this?

Comment: Sorry im not sure. Maybe its already in master. Looks like it could be this: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/idl/programs/relations-derivation/src/lib.rs